# Specific heat of aluminium as a function of temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

I am trying to find the curve describing the specific heat of aluminum as a function of temperature between about 50K to 300K(or room temperature) for an experiment I am doing.
Ultimately I need to integrate between those bounds.
Google doesn't seem to provide any useful links. I was able to find some values at specific temperatures, but not enough data to produce a curve.

Any references to places that might contain this sort of data are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For aluminum 3003F between 4K and 300K see:
http://www.cryogenics.nist.gov/MPropsMAY/3003F%20Aluminum/3003FAluminum_rev.htm

For alumimum 5083 between 4K and 300K see:
http://www.cryogenics.nist.gov/MPropsMAY/5083%20Aluminum/5083Aluminum_rev.htm

for aluminum 6061-T6 between 4K and 300K see:
http://www.cryogenics.nist.gov/MPropsMAY/6061%20Aluminum/6061_T6Aluminum_rev.htm

8th degree polynomials